# How to read zipped gzip csv files saved in cloud storage in apache beam without extracting

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have GZIP zipped csv files getting uploaded in cloud storage through third party. I am using apache beam continuous streaming  pipeline to read zipped files metadata(file name , full path).I have one more requirement to read first line and last line of this csv files.
I am using following codes to get all zipped file that is being added to cloud storage bucket folder.

```
    pipeline.apply("MatchFile(s)", FileIO.match()
            .filepattern(zipFilePath)
            .continuously(Duration.standardMinutes(1), Watch.Growth.never()))
            .apply(Window.<~>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
            .apply("Get Compressed File(s)", ParDo.of(new GetCompressedFile()));

static class GetCompressedFile extends DoFn<MatchResult.Metadata, Void> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) throws ParseException {

            ResourceId inputFile = context.element().resourceId();
            String fileName = inputFile.getFilename();
            String currentDirectoryPath = inputFile.getCurrentDirectory().toString();
```

I am able to get zipped file name and path but I am not able to read csv files without extracting it. I tried some google answer to read zipped file but that is not reading from cloud storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to read zipped file by using following codes without extracting it. May be it will help somebody.

```
    pipeline.apply("MatchFile(s)", FileIO.match()
            .filepattern(zipFilePath)
            .continuously(Duration.standardMinutes(1), Watch.Growth.never()))
            .apply(Window.<MatchResult.Metadata>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
            .apply(FileIO.readMatches().withCompression(GZIP))
            .apply("Read Files",ParDo.of(new ReadFilesGZIP()));

    pipeline.run();
}

static class ReadsFilesGZIP extends DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile,String>{
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context){
        FileIO.ReadableFile file = context.element();


            ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = file.getCompression().readDecompressed(FileSystems.open(file.getMetadata().resourceId()));
            try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Channels.newInputStream(readableByteChannel)))) {
                String line;
                Stream<String> fileLines = r.lines();
```

}

Comment: Do we have a python version of the above @akash kumar

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you want, but you can read your files like that

```
    pipeline.apply("MatchFile(s)", FileIO.match()
            .filepattern(zipFilePath)
            .continuously(Duration.standardMinutes(1), Watch.Growth.never()))
            .apply(Window.<~>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
            .apply(FileIO.readMatches().withCompression(Compression.GZIP))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, IdLine>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(@Element FileIO.ReadableFile file, OutputReceiver<IdLine> out) throws IOException {
                        String content = file.readFullyAsUTF8String();
                        System.out.println(content);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(file.open(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
                        String l;
                        StringBuffer stackLine = new StringBuffer();
                        while ((l = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        ....
                        }
                    }
                }));
```

Comment: thanks but content will print only file name. I tried same kind of codes but used file.getCompression().readDecompressed I am posting answer here.